# How to minimize the entire editor area on closing a view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have opened a view created by me for example I opened a file editor view.
Now on closing that particular view, I want the entire editor area to get minimized.
An editor area may contain more than one view, so on closing my view entire editor area should get minimized.

I already put a listener to the view but further I am not able to achieve the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it is meant to be easily done, considering [`EditorStack`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/EditorStack.java.htm) is part of the `org.eclipse.ui.`**`internal`** package.

You still can have a look at the [`PartStack#setMinimized(boolean)` implementation](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/EditorStack.java.htm#296), to see if it can help.

Comment: Can you suggest me any solution for the problem I am facing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509679/how-to-provide-a-custom-component-in-the-existing-web-page-editor-palette

Comment: @Abhishnek: I just look at your question (quite similar to the un-answered thread http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=205702&S=6f77b4a4edc54fb8b085ee5622bd0f0d), but I don't have enough experience on this issue to be of much help.